# Android Animated App Walkthrough

Tags: android

I have a project where my customer asked to create animated help for each screen. What he means by animated help is the one like when you start a new emulator, it shows a hand that tells you what to do. I would really appreciate your help guys if you can give me any clues where to start.

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you search online a bit before asking us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to recreate the default help by using [this Library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) and some Bitmaps (for the hand you mentioned).